# How to send Swift email with attachment loaded from MongoDB GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, swiftmailer, gridfs

We use MongoDB GridFS to store attachments in our CRM. Now we should be able to send selected attachments in email message using SwiftMailer. Is there a way to do it properly without storing files to disk first? GridFS PHP api provides file as the following object.

> http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfsfile.php#mongogridfsfile.props.file

For downloading file in browser we can stream it directly without tmp files. Does anyone solve this for attaching the GridFS files to email?

**Update 1:** I just realized I can create an attachment from bytes data e.g.

```
$mf=$a->getFile()->getMongoGridFSFile();
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($mf->getBytes(), $mf->getFilename(), $a->getMimeType());
```

... but cant imagine it to work properly for large files as they are kept in memory while sending ...